# Symfony / EasyAdmin goes to nowhere

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5, easyadmin

I'm new here, this is my first message and I really need some helps!

I'm starting a project with symfony and have installed EasyAdmin 2.3
Everything was ok until this morning.
The URL http://localhost:8000/admin/ goes to http://localhost:8000/admin/?action=list&entity=User and I just see a white page without any errors mentions.
Can you please help me?

Here is my code in config/routes/easy_admin.yaml

```
easy_admin_bundle:
    resource: '@EasyAdminBundle/Controller/EasyAdminController.php'
    prefix: /admin
    type: annotation
```

Then I've written my code like this in package/easy_admin.yaml

```
easy_admin:
    entities:
        User:
            class: App\Entity\User
            list:
              fields:
                  - id
                  - prenom
                  - nom
                  - adresse
                  - telephone
                  - password
                  - email
                  - { property: 'roles', label: 'Rôles', type: json_array}
            form:
              fields:
                  - email
                  - password
                  - nom
                  - prenom
                  - adresse
                  - telephone
                  - { property: 'roles', label: 'Rôles', type: choice, type_options: {expanded: true, multiple: true, choices: {'Utilisateur':'ROLE_USER', 'Administrateur':'ROLE_ADMIN'}}}
        Booking:
            class: App\Entity\Booking
        Chef:
            class: App\Entity\Chef
            list:
                fields:
                  - id
                  - nom
                  - prenom
                  - { property: 'image', type: 'image', base_path: '%app.path.chef_images%' }
                  - presentation
                  - type_de_cuisine
                  - menu
            form:
                fields:
                  - nom
                  - prenom
                  - { property: 'imageFile', type: 'vich_image' }
                  - presentation
                  - type_de_cuisine
                  - menu
        Menu:
            class: App\Entity\Menu
        TypeCuisine:
            class: App\Entity\TypeCuisine
        Commentaire:
            class: App\Entity\Commentaire
```

Access in security.yaml is

```
access_control:
         - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: seems it's auto-redirect to the first page it found , here : the user page.
When you say "white page", you mean a real white page, or the easyadmin template with no data?

Comment: real white page going on an entity/list and not showing anything. but that really took me 2days to get over it. I've erased everything, cloned back our project (hallelujah Github :)) and installed a previous version.

Answer (score 1):

I've erased Full-Calendar Bundle that I had previously then installed a previous version of EasyAdmin :

```
php bin/console composer require easycorp/easyadmin-bundle:^2.3
```

The newest version (3.0) doesn't work for me, seems like unstable on my project built with symfony 5 and I don't know why.
I needed also to fully erase what I had by search "easycorp" :

- files in public/vendors folder: "Easycorp"
- lines in composer.json, composer.lock and symfony.lock
- lines in bundles.php (EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\EasyAdminBundle::class => ['all' => true],)

It's really frustrating. I really wanted to make an upgrade from 2.0 to 3.0 but the migration doesn't work even when I looked out through Symfony docs.

So for now, I'll keep my 2.3.9 version, it works fine, I'm waiting for improvements, obviously not on my side.

Comment: issue is solved. I had also an error into an entity which blocked EasyAdmin.

Comment: Could you update this answer to include your final solution, assuming you got 3.0 to work? Feel free to do a complete edit - answers saying that it previously did not work is not useful to future readers. You can always move that to the question if you think it was part of the original problem.